# Calcular fecha actual de forma automática

Tags: django

Saludos a toda la comunidad espero me puedan ayudar estoy intentando tomar la fecha actual de manera automática, y mostrarla en un template de Django 1.9

Comment: Lea por aquí :  [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) & [`settings.DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar la documentacion oficial:

```
Fecha:{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

[image: Resultado]
[Documentacion Oficial django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#now)